# NHibernate and generic version

Tags: nhibernate

I'm just getting started with NHibernate and reading blogs and articles from all over.
many of them reference a session.Get<> methods for generic types, but this is not available for me. I only get the session.Get(Type class, object id) methods.

Why is this? Am I missing a reference? Or has this something to do with the NHibernate version I'm using. Wich is NHIbernate 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following definition, they're implemented by the ISession interface. Which would mean that whenever you have an object which implements ISession, you should have both methods.

```
namespace NHibernate
{
    public interface ISession : IDisposable
    {
        ...
        T Get<T>(object id);
        object Get(string entityName, object id);
    }
}
```

Are you sure you have the most recent version of the [NHibernate assembly](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.0.GA/NHibernate-2.1.0.GA-bin.zip/download)?

Comment: I downloaded the latest release tonight.
this is mye exmaple code:
public Person GetByPersonId(Guid personId)
{
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = (new Configuration()).Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
    ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    return (Person) session.Get(typeof (Person), personId);
}

this is the only .Get method I'm able to access. I have only referenced the NHibernate.dll